# How can I pop a Kendo dialog box within a vue method

Tags: vue.js, kendo-ui, dialog

I have a method within a `Vue` object that needs to show a `Kendo` dialog box. I can show one of the standard (alert, confirm, prompt) boxes, but not a dialog box.

I have googled the heck out of this, but all I find are examples for `jQuery`, `Angular`, etc.

```
methods: {
  // target for all setTimeout calls. You can only have one target on the page.
  moretime: function() {
    WHAT_DO_I_CALL_HERE({
      modal: true,
      title: 'Your session is about to end',
      closable: false,
      actions: [
        {
          text: 'Yes',
          primary: true,
          action: function(e) {
            this.addtime()
          },
        },
        {
          text: 'Logout',
          action: function(e) {
            axios.get('/logout')
            window.location.replace(this.return_address)
          },
        },
      ],
      content: 'Do you need more time?',
    })

    // this works but isn't custom enough.
    // kendo.confirm("Do you need more time?")
    //     .done(function () {
    //         this.addtime();
    //     }.bind(this))
    //     .fail(function () {
    //         axios.get('/logout');
    //         window.location.replace(this.return_address);
    //     }.bind(this));
    return
  },
},
```

I've tried `kendo.dialog`, and `kendoDialog`, but all of them are not valid functions.  My IDE shows me lists of methods that follow `kendo.`, but none of them are `dialog`, or `Dialog`.

If I were using `jQuery`, this would work, since `jQuery` provides a `kendoDialog` method.

If `kendo.confirm` is available, why isn't `kendo.dialog`?

How are you *supposed* to do this?

Comment: Don't have time to turn this into an answer but I think the trick is to use "ref" similar to how things are shown here: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-vue-ui/components/popups/tooltip/referencing-existing-instances/ to get reference to instance of the modal